# How does on update Html.CheckBoxFor using AngularJS ng-model?

Tags: javascript, c#, angularjs, asp.net-mvc, razor

I'm using asp.net MVC 5 and am making a checkbox using Html.CheckBoxFor.

```
<div class="col-md-6">
    @Html.CheckBoxFor(m => m.active, new { 
        @class = "form-control populate", @id = 'EditActive',
        @ng_model = "editFormData.active"
    })
</div>
```

When I set angularjs editFormData after an ajax call, the value is correct when I output it to the screen as {{ editFormData }} but the checkbox doesn't show as being checked.

```
datatableApp.controller('EditFormController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getEditStreet = function(streetID) {
        $http.post('@Url.Action(Model.GetFormControllerFunctionName, Model.GetFormControllerName)', "{ @Model.JavascriptEditPropertyName : " + streetID + "}").then(function(response) {
                alert("success");
                $scope.editFormData = response.data.ResultObject;
            },
            function(response) {
                alert("fail" + response.statusText);
            });
    };
}]);
```

The resultobject contains an active field that is showing up correctly as true or false.

How can I get the razor version of the checkbox to check?

Comment: How you setting `$scope.editFormData` value? Have you want to set `active: true` after AJAX callback (better to show both `editFormData` and AJAX callback code)?

Comment: @TetsuyaYamamoto I updated the question with the angularjs. Inside of the resultobject is a property called active.

Comment: How `response.data.ResultObject` looks like (I think it returns JSON object after POST)? Try result data serialization to reveal `active` property value in `ng-model`: `$scope.editFormData = @Html.Raw(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(response.data.ResultObject));` or `JSON.stringify` if angular controller being placed in separate JS file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out. Apparently when you modify certain values in some cases you need to have $scope.apply(). Not sure what all those cases are but I added it and it is working perfectly now.

```
datatableApp.controller('EditFormController', ['$scope', '$http', function($scope, $http) {
    $scope.getEditStreet = function(streetID) {
        $http.post('@Url.Action(Model.GetFormControllerFunctionName, Model.GetFormControllerName)', "{ @Model.JavascriptEditPropertyName : " + streetID + "}").then(function(response) {
                alert("success");
                $scope.editFormData = response.data.ResultObject;
                $scope.$apply();
            },
            function(response) {
                alert("fail" + response.statusText);
            });
    };
}]);
```